# MongoDB sort if value equals to something

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to sort in Mongodb -> if field equals to some value?

for example:

something like this

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort : { username : 'john' ? -1 : 1, posts: 1 } }
   ]
)
```

If I want to sort let's say `username` field..
If username equals to "john" put user first in results

Comment: Just to clarify what you're trying to do, are you trying to sort the remaining "non-Johns" in a normal sort order and just prioritise a specific user here above all the others?

Answer (score 2):

### Not possible

> If MongoDB cannot obtain the sort order via an index scan, then MongoDB uses a **top-k sort algorithm**. This algorithm buffers the first **k** results (or last, depending on the sort order) seen so far by the underlying index or collection access. If at any point the memory footprint of these k results exceeds 32 megabytes, the query will fail.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#limit-results

We cannot override sort algorithm, but we can do some ticky solution.

**Solution 1.** (Good performance)

Add extra field (i.e. `order`). For `"username" : "john"` set `0` value and for other usernames, set `1` value. Create new index {order:1, username:1, posts:1}

Now when you sort by indexed fields, **john** will be at the first place.

**Solution 2** (Bad performance)

We do the same, but dynamically.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      order: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$username",
              "john"
            ]
          },
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      order: 1,
      username: 1,
      posts: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dcgyGk-5jeP)

Comment: I don't understand the difference between Solution 1 and 2.
In "solution 1" you meant that I need to save one more field in DB itself?

Comment: @israelkusaev the difference: if you store un mongodb document with order field, you can index it. Now, if you have 1m records, sorting will be very fast `O(log n)` cause mongo uses indexes. Solution two, for 1m records, sorting will be very slow `O(N log K)`

Comment: Thank you. I had to use solution number 2, since my sorting depends on the person requesting the results (their locale). So couldn't create a static order. I found about a 15% performance decrease for my API after implementing this, but I had to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this, I think.

*Input documents:*

```
{ "username" : "jack", "posts" : "hello world" }
{ "username" : "chris", "posts" : "java programming" }
{ "username" : "krish", "posts" : "mongo mongo" }
{ "username" : "john", "posts" : "rock-n-roll" }
```

*The query:*

```
db.users.aggregate( [
  { 
      $facet: {
          input_user: [
              { $match: { username: INPUT_NAME } }
          ],
          other: [
              { $match: { username: { $ne: INPUT_NAME } } },
              { $sort: { username: 1 } }
          ]
      } 
  },
  {
      $project: { result: { $concatArrays: [ "$input_user", "$other" ] } }
  }
] )
```

*The output:*

When the `INPUT_NAME = 'john'`, then the order of the `username`'s is:
"john", "chris", "jack" and "krish".

And, when the `INPUT_NAME = 'some other'`, it is: "chris", "jack", "john" and "krish".

---

*NOTE:*

The above solution works fine with small collections *but* will not use the indexes defined on the `username`+ `posts` fields - and this may cause a slower performance with larger collections.

So, an option is to use two queries and merge the results. In such a case an index defined like this will be used by the query filter as well as the sort operations: `{ username: 1, posts: 1 } }`.

For example:

```
let result_1 = db.users.find( { username: { $ne: INPUT_NAME } } ).sort( { username: 1, posts: 1 } ).toArray()

let result = db.users.find( { username: INPUT_NAME } ).sort( { username: 1, posts: 1 } ).toArray().concat(result_1)
```

The queries can be aggregations, which will have the advantage of using more memory for sort operation. The index will be used for both the match and sort operations.

- [$sort and Memory
  Restrictions(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-and-memory-restrictions).
- [$sort and Memory
  Restrictions(find.cursor)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/index.html#restrictions)

Comment: I also thought this solution, but the problem occures when records are too much, so $facet can generate documents greater than 16Mb